# Source not found. TextView

Tags: android, xml

I am a novice in Java and Android. I want to change the text on activity via setText().
This is an XML-code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.p0081viewbyid.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/myText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is a part of java - code :

```
package com.example.p0081viewbyid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
        myTextView.setText("New text in TextView");//application close on this place

        if (savedInstanceState == null) 
            {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

This application close on setText method with cause "Source not found". Where is my error? I was tried to fix it changing it such as:

```
myTextView.setText("New text in TextView".toString());
myTextView.setText(Integer.toString("New text in TextView"))
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: are you sure textview belongs to `activity_main.xml` and not to the fragment layout

Comment: myTextView.setText("New text in TextView".toString());  
myTextView.setText(Integer.toString("New text in TextView"))  Both these will be errors

Comment: Oh, it is really in fragment layout. Thanks. I try to change it.